# MongoDB query in controller

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am new to MVC with nodejs and have spent alot of time researching how to solve my error but have still come up with no solution and really need some assistance. Through the cli when I run npm start: the correct data is shown from mongodb but I have not been able to display on my web page.
My route is:

```
router.get('/gallery/description', artController.description);
```

the controller is:

```
var paintings = require('../models/get_painting');
console.log('this is the returned value of paintings ' + paintings);

const description = function(req, res) {res.render('description', 
{title:'description', art: 'this is what i get ' + paintings)});};
```

The model:

```
var paintings = require('./painting_schema');


var query = paintings.find({}).then(function(picture){
    console.log(picture);
    return picture;
  }).catch(function(err){});

module.exports = query;
```

As I said the console.log in the controller returns the correct information but when passing it into the description variable all that displays on the webpage is [object promise].

view:

```
extends layout

block content
  .container-fluid
    each item in art
      p= item
```

Comment: Can you add the template to the question?

Comment: @MikaS is the view what you were looking for? I have added it.

Comment: There's a lot wrong here. I suggest you get your controller working with all your code together rather than spread out in separate modules and go from there.

Comment: even though it may seem as though there is alot wrong there all of it works as intended and is live on our school project host. the only thing that doesnt work is the data from mongo db to the page. I can run npm start in the cli and it returns all the correct information. But displaying it is not happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume this happens because the `query` is a promise (technically, it's not a promise until you use [exec()](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/promises.html), but you can use it as a promise). You export the promise, but not its result. So if you use `await` to wait for it to finish then you will get the painting documents rather than the promise itself.

It's a bit hard for me to tell you how to fix it with your current style. Here is how I would structure it:

Inside the `artController` file:

```
module.exports.description = async (req, res) => {
  const paintings = await Painting.find({})

  res.render('description', { 
    title: 'description',
    art: 'this is what i get ' + paintings
  });

}
```

Notice the `async` and `await`.

The model should contain your Painting schema. Remove the query inside it. If you create a model with `mongoose.model(Painting, paintingSchema)` then you can fetch it inside the controller file with `const Painting = mongoose.model('Painting');`.

Comment: I did some digging on async and await your method seems to alot cleaner overall and a bit easier to understand. Especially for this being my first time i was able to narrow down some great information. I will mark this as a solution due to the fact it points in the direction of a better/easier outcome.